# Why is my express.js server failing the initial chunk stream request and not the following one?

Tags: node.js, express, safari, google-cloud-storage, video-streaming

I am building a video streaming website and I am streaming mp4 files over an express.js server with the help of google cloud storage. In safari I have been having trouble with being able to play the video.

After the initial request that safari sends to my server with the range of bytes 0-1, safari decides then how much it wants. The first image is the request after the initial 0-1 byte request which to me seems like it failed

[image: First Network Request to Express Server]

This next image is the following request which went through okay
[image: second request]

My questions is why does this happen and how can I be able to fix it ?

My code that handles this is the following

```
//remoteFile comes the the google cloud storage library
//it works similar to the 'fs' library 

 remoteFile
        .createReadStream(null,{ start: start , end: end })
        .on("response", (response) => {
            const head = {
                "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${response.headers['content-length']}`,
                "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
                "Content-Length": chunksize,
                "Content-Type": response.headers['content-type'],
            };
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(response.headers))
            res.writeHead(206, head);
        }) 
        .on("error",  (err) => {
            console.log("Something happend to the stream" + err);
            res.status(500).send(err);
          })
        .on("end", () => {
            console.log("video complete");
        })
        .pipe(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that some browsers send a range in the initial request, but others simply don't. In able to fix this, you can add a conditional for this.

For example, use this code from [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/Dunebook/Videostreaming-app/blob/master/server/app.js):

```
app.get('/video/:id', function(req, res) {
  const path = `assets/${req.params.id}.mp4`;
  const stat = fs.statSync(path);
  const fileSize = stat.size;
  const range = req.headers.range;
  if (range) {
    console.log('we have range', range);
    const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-")
    const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10)
    const end = parts[1] 
      ? parseInt(parts[1], 10)
      : fileSize-1
      console.log(parts)
    const chunksize = (end-start)+1
    const file = fs.createReadStream(path, {start, end})
    const head = {
      'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
      'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
      'Content-Length': chunksize,
      'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
    }
    res.writeHead(206, head);
    file.pipe(res);
  } else {
    console.log('no range', range);
    const head = {
      'Content-Length': fileSize,
      'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
    }
    res.writeHead(200, head)
    fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res)
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I have something similar to this but I am still getting not able to play videos on safari. For some reason I believe it has to do with video's content length  that have byte ranges of 7 digits or longer. I have a video that is 6 digits long in bytes and that is able to be played on safari but not any other videos